# Dotnet Core authentication CorrelationFailed

Tags: authentication, .net-core, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm trying to setup authentication on a brand new dotnet core app.
I'm using IdentityServer that is working fine as it is being used for other apps.

I get an error that does not say much more than "Correlation Failed".
Looking at the output in VS2017 I see a warning a bit before the exception that say the following:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Warning:
>   .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.

Here is my config:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyAwesomeCookie";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = IdentityServerConstants.IdentityServerUrl;
                options.ClientId = "myclientid";
                options.ClientSecret = "supersecuresecret";

                //options.CorrelationCookie.Name = "something";

                foreach (var s in myScopes)
                {
                    options.Scope.Add(s);
                }
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/");

                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;


            });
    }
```

I modified some values for security reasons and I excluded the event hoocking as I believe that it is irrelevant.

I could track it down to this file:
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs

If the last method on this file returns false, then you get the "Correlation Failed" error.

However, I spent a long time googling the error and could not find how to fix it. I'm probably missing something trivial in the config...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation for why this is the case, but I encountered the same error and managed to resolve it by removing this line:

```
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, which was caused by the following option being set in the `RouteOptions`:

`options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;`

This caused the `state` query parameter to be lower cased when performing the redirects back to the application.  Since state is case sensitive, it caused the `state property not found` error.